# how to unload the files loaded by the "require" statement in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have bunch of classes

```
files = ["payment_type","payment_type_ticket_mapping","price_modifier_ticket_delta_mapping","user","revenue_type","revenue_type_group","tax","tax_type","punch"]
files.each {|file| require file }
```

that are required to fulfill the requirement of `Marshal.load` but when I run the rsepc they give me the following error

```
/spec/factories.rb:6: undefined method `admin_login_url' for #<ActionView::Base:0xb62e0228> (ActionView::TemplateError)
```

When I remove that reuire statement it works fine but that statement is necessary for the functionality of `Marshal.load` how to unload the loaded classes by require statement after the work is done.

Comment: Interesting.. are you using url helpers in factories?

Comment: I have resolved that problem using the config.cache_classes = true in the environment.

Comment: @Anup Write your comment as and answer so that to make the question appear as answered.

Comment: @Regedor - Thanks for pointing it out I have added my comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved that problem using the `config.cache_classes = true` in the environment.

Answer (score 1):

To unload a file just remove all its definitions, and then remove the file name from the loaded file list `$"`, like the following:

```
$".grep(/#{file}/).each { |f| $".delete(f) }
```